# Would communication of information from the future require a block time structure?

Tags: faster-than-light, time-travel, wormholes

If faster-than-light travel (through wormhole tunneling or some other exotic means) was discovered in future, such that it allows information to be communicated from the future to the present, what would that indicate about the structure of time?

Some might argue that this indicates a block-type structure for time, since such a technological discovery occurred at one specific spacetime event. But if information is allowed to go backward ONLY from that specific moment in the future, does it necessitate  a block-type structure for the universe or is this just an illusion?

Comment: After @safesphere's comment to my response, I'm not sure if this is a Physics question.

Answer (score 1):

A hypothetical information transfer from the future rules out the growing block time universe model. In this model, the past and present exist, but the future does not exist yet. If the future does not exist, we could not possibly receive any information from there. Therefore logically there could be no communication from the future to the last or present in the growing block time universe.

This logic does not imply that the universe is or is not growing block or that communication from the future is possible.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growing_block_universe

EDIT

As mentioned in comments, the "block universe" or "block time universe" is different from the "growing block time universe". The block universe model assumes that the past, present, and future all exist. In other words, the 4-dimensional spacetime is static. This is the model used by Relativity, both Special and General. Strictly speaking, General Relativity does not prohibit time loops under exotic conditions. However, considerations of causality put almost unrealistically strict requirements on them.

Nevertheless, time loops do not automatically require a static spacetime. For example, time loops with non-static outcomes can exist in the Multiple Worlds model, as well as in the models where the present is a consequence of both the past and future or in the models where the past obeys some uncertainty principle.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternalism_(philosophy_of_time)

Comment: I thought "block time universe" was distinct from a "growing block time universe." The former says past, present, future all exist, while the latter says only past & present exist. The first sentence of this post mixes up the two.

Comment: @SpiralRain Thanks for your comment. I've updated the answer to avoid a confusion.

Comment: Safesphere...the models "where the present is a consequence of both the past and future," can you point to those models online or perhaps share their names? I likely have studied them, but a closer look is warranted. Thank you!

Comment: @NeilHopwood Sorry, it's been a while, I no longer have a reference. My point here was rather conceptual that any such model would be a suspect for the possibility of time loops.

Comment: Fair enough. Let me ask this then...IF the future had any direct influence on the present, would that mean time is not static? Of course that implies that the future/present at least to a minor extent co-create each other going both ways (in this case for reasons I won't belabor, this information exchange would also still maintain consistency/causality despite the future's influence). Thanks again.

Comment: @NeilHopwood Time is static only if the past is determined (can't change and has no uncertainty). Then it doesn't matter if the future influences the present. Time (4D spacetime precisely) would be static anyway. Dynamic time means either (1) that things that already have happened can change and we can learn that they happened differently from the way we thought they happened or (2) that things in the past can be uncertain, such that they haven't happened yet until some future event requires a very specific cause in the past. I suspect physical time is dynamic and the past very much uncertain.